# How to properly await a list of tasks that's part of a tuple?

Tags: c#, async-await

I need to create a list of `Task`s, which have some different parameter passed. I also need to keep track of the parameter. So I thought about doing it like this

```
List<(Task<MyResult> tasks, int offset)> myListOfTasks = new();
if (myParam != 0)
{  
    for(int i = 0; i < myParam; i++)
    {
        myListOfTasks.Add((service.LoadData(myParam+i, cancellationToken), i));
    }   
}
```

Now I would like to await the tasks and construct a `List<(MyResult, int)>` from the above. I think I could just `for` loop over the `myListOfTasks` and do `await` for each one, while storing the offset, but that feels like it would do them one by one. I know of `Task.WhenAll` but I am not sure how to use it in this context, if I can.

How do I countruct a list of `(result, intParam)` from above while doing all of them at once?

Comment: You don't need the offset and hence the tuple. Lists and arrays maintain the order of their elements. What is this code trying to do, and what does `LoadData` do? If you try to use multiple concurrent connections to read from a database you can easily *increase* delays as connections block each other.

Comment: As for the question itself, `var tasks=Enumerable.Range(0,myParam).Select(i=>service.LoadData(myParam+i, cancellationToken));` and then `await Task.WhenAll(tasks);`

Comment: Maybe you can wait all task : await Task.WaitAll(myListOfTasks.Select(x => x.tasks)) and then take their results : myListOfTasks.Select<(MyResult result, int param)>(x => new( x.tasks.Result, x.offset));

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos The code contacts a service, which will return an object for a result. I want to pair the object returned with the value of (myParam+i) with which it was called.

Comment: Post the actual code then. `I want to pair the object returned with the value of (myParam+i) with which it was called` you don't have to because [Task.WhenAll](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.whenall?view=net-7.0#system-threading-tasks-task-whenall-1(system-collections-generic-ienumerable((system-threading-tasks-task((-0)))))) returns results in the order of the tasks. `var results=await Task.WhenAll(tasks)` will give you the results in the order of the tasks

Comment: Or you can check the `.Result` of the completed tasks. There's just no way to use `Task.WhenAll` with a class, record or tuple, only a collection of tasks

Comment: Do you have any need for the `offset` before the tasks are awaited? Or it becomes useful only after the task results are available?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Task.WhenAll` and then grab task results:

```
await Task.WhenAll(myListOfTasks.Select(t => t.tasks).ToArray());

return myListOfTasks.Select(t => (t.tasks.Result, t.offset)).ToList();
```

Comment: You are creating a array of tasks just to feed it to `Task.WhenAll` that, in turn, will create another array of the same tasks.

Comment: I understand what I'm doing. You propose to create initially array of tasks and use just Select with index when generating result?

Comment: `Task.WhenAll` accepts an `IEnumerable<Task>` also